# Is there any simple small app for SQL coding on Ubuntu?

Tags: programming

I need to practice SQL for my database class, and wanted a simple, hassle-free app that would let me write code and execute it. Does this exist?

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com has real data that you can perform all sorts of queries on (I'm commenting because this fits "practising SQL", but might not be what you're looking for)

Comment: what is your database? mysql? sqlite? progress? you can even try sql online: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: MySQL. I know of Oracle and MySQL workbench, but I need a plain 'ol type, click run, save, etc. It would be pleasant if it had a dark theme.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day I thought databases with [SquirrelSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) and the students did not complain. It is a Java programme, so all you need is to [download the jar file](http://www.squirrelsql.org/#installation) and run it.

Naturally, you need some DBMS to practice, in this regard I recommend [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/). It is available from the official repositories, you can install it directly with `apt`:

`sudo apt install firebird2.5-classic`

Follow on the [Ubuntu Wiki on Firebird](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5) for the examples and the first steps interacting with Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite3 is worth looking at. It is built in to Mobile phones and tablets to handle data like your contacts, app data, diary etc. SQLite3 studio is its own interface and can be a really useful app. It is all free.
Best wishes in your studies